# Is this an object in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, oop

When I write this piece of code in Java:

```
int []Array;
Array = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
```

Is "Array" an object? If so, What type?

Comment: `Array` here is not a type, it's a variable.

Comment: `Array` is a variable that holds the value of a reference to an array object that was created with `new int[] {...}` notation.

Comment: Please take some time to read the Java tutorials: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html

Answer (score 4):

From [Java Tutorials: Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) (emphasys mine):

> An array is a container **object** that holds a fixed number of values of a **single type**.

From this sentence, the answer to your questions:

> Is `Array` an object?

A: Yes.

> If so, What type?

A: `int[]`.

Comment: More precisely, "Array" is a *reference* that points to an int[].

Comment: @AndyThomas I prefer to use the words in the official tutorial :).

Comment: You should probably say that the _Array variable will hold an array of the specified type._ as the tutorial states.

Answer (score 2):

In java array is consider as object of the array declared type.

Try this one to get the type of the array.

```
System.out.println(Array.getClass().getComponentType());
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be confusing, but you don't create an array with a type called "Array." You define it relative to the type of its contents.

So you create an array of integers like this

```
int[] first = new int[10];
```

or

```
int[] second = new int[] {3, 5, 7, 9};
```

The brackets tell you it's an array type. And `first` and `second` are both objects.

See this [resource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) for more details.

Now just to confuse matters, there is a utility class called `Arrays`. This [class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) is useful for things like sorting, searching, and other common operations.

Answer (score 0):

If you write the piece of code, as given, then `Array` is an object of type int[] (as stated in comments).

also an Object (rule of thumb) is "everything" whose type-declarator begins with a majuscle
(uppercase letter)

```
//short intro to fields:
access modifier       | static | final    | type                  | name
public/private/2 more | or not | constant | primitve or Object<T> | lowercase identifier
```

Examples

```
private int a;
public static final String greeting = "Welcome!";
```

thus in general fields and methods are named lowercase.

the only types that do not generate objects are the so called primitives:

```
int
boolean
char
short
long
double
...
```

these also have Wrapper-Classes providing additional functionality

```
Int
Double
Boolean
//and so on;)
```